# Optional in FormDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using MS bot framework and FormDialog to ask the user to fill a form. 
I would like some of the parameters to be optional and therefore added [Optional] indication to them:

```
[Prompt("Please specify if you have any additional requirements")]
[Optional]
string AdditionalRequirement { get; set; }
```

However, these questions still appear when the bot is filling up the form, and there is no way for the user to skip them (for instance just type "enter" or "skip")

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is this the expected behavior? Is it possible to have a parameter that the user can skip in case it is not necessary?

---

update: seems the expected behaviour is that the optional parameters always show and there are certain words that can be understood as skipping the question, such as "No preference".

An answer that would explain how to add "skip" as one of the words to skip the question would be accepted.

Comment: What happens if you write "skip"?

Comment: Skip is not one of the no preference options. I could write "No preference" and that would put a null in the field. This is the optional behaviour, so it turnes out.

Comment: Based on the source code it seems that "no", "none", "I don't care" would be also valid words to skip the optional field. What behavior are you looking?

Comment: I would like to write "skip" to skip the optional field. If you have a small code sample for doing that I would very much appreciate it. Updated the question too.

Comment: Great. I just added an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think on two possible ways of achieving this (I couldn't test them, sorry!)

1) Decorate the optional field with a `Template` attribute, specifying the `TemplateUsage.NoPreference` usage as this.

```
[Template(TemplateUsage.NoPreference, "skip")]
```

2) Add the Skip term to the `NoPreference` array of the `FormBuilder<T>` configuration. Something like:

```
public static IFormBuilder<T> CreateCustomForm<T>()
    where T : class
{
    var form = new FormBuilder<T>();
    var noPreferenceTerms = form.Configuration.NoPreference.ToList();
    noPreferenceTerms.Add("skip");
    form.Configuration.NoPreference = noPreferenceTerms.ToArray();

    return form;
}
```

That then you can use like:

```
 return CreateCustomForm<MyForm>()
```

Comment: The first step is not required, it only changes how NoPreference is shown. Except for that, works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to add a Optional annotation to a field. What I know you can do is to pass a delegate to a method (or an anonymous method) where you can perform a check to see if the current field is active or not. If not, the field will not be prompted to the user. Heres a brief example:

```
public static IForm<MyForm> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<MyForm>()
        .Field(nameof(AdditionalRequirement), active: IsAdditionalRequirementActive)
        .Build();
}

private static bool IsAdditionalRequirementActive(MyForm state)
{
    if (state.SomeOtherField == "Value")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```